# MySQL add privilege to user. Now user cannot access DB

Tags: mysql

The MySQL user I am using for my site, could not truncate a table it needed to.

So I wanted to add delete permissions to just that table.

I ran this from a command line:

```
GRANT DELETE ON my_db.my_table TO my_mysql_user@localhost;
```

The output was

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

Now the user (who prevously could) cannot connect to the database at all:

> mysql_connect() [http://php.net/function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'my_mysql_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: try to login as my_mysql_user@localhost with no password (you added no IDENTIFIED BY clause to your grant, and i think this new user @localhost is taking precedence over same user @%)

Comment: @guido how would you add the IDENTIFIED BY clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How was the user created originally? If the user@host mask was something like `... TO my_mysql_user@%`, the localhost version you just granted delete to will be an entirely new user.

Comment: Ok, so what do I need to do to fix it.. Do I delete the @localhost user and add permissions to @% user?

Comment: I checked the mysql.users table and there were 2 like you said, I deleted the one with Host = "localhost" it still says access denied when I visit my site.

Comment: I had to run  FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ... That fixed it :)

Comment: depends on your needs. if you want your username to available no matter where your connection's coming from, then yeah, use the @% version. If you want to restrict your account to only be able to do deletes if it's a local connection, then add your password to this new account (`set password for my_mysql_user@loacalhost==password('blahblah')`)